# For each pixel in a image, get the color, pixel position, and coordinates relatively to the image

Tags: .net, vb.net, colors, bitmap, gdi+

### Scenario

I'm trying to write a function that will use the structure below, `PixelInfo`, to return a collection on where for each pixel in the source image, will store the `Color`, pixel position, and a `Point` with coordinates location relatively to the image:

```
<Serializable>
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure PixelInfo

    Public ReadOnly Property Color As Color
        Get
            Return Me.colorB
        End Get
    End Property
    Private ReadOnly colorB As Color

    Public ReadOnly Property Position As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.positionB
        End Get
    End Property
    Private ReadOnly positionB As Integer

    Public ReadOnly Property Location As Point
        Get
            Return Me.locationB
        End Get
    End Property
    Private ReadOnly locationB As Point

    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Sub New(ByVal color As Color,
                   ByVal position As Integer,
                   ByVal location As Point)

        Me.colorB = color
        Me.positionB = position
        Me.locationB = location

    End Sub

End Structure
```

This is the function:

```
<DebuggerStepThrough>
<Extension>
Iterator Function GetPixelInfo(ByVal sender As Image) As IEnumerable(Of PixelInfo)

    Dim bytesPerPixel As Integer = (Image.GetPixelFormatSize(sender.PixelFormat) \ 8)

    If (bytesPerPixel <> 3) AndAlso (bytesPerPixel <> 4) Then
        Throw New NotImplementedException(
        message:="Only PixelFormats that has 3 or 4 bytes-per-pixel are supported.")

    Else
        ' Lock the bitmap's bits.
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = DirectCast(sender, Bitmap)
        Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height)
        Dim bmpData As BitmapData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                                 bmp.PixelFormat)

        ' Get the address of the first line.
        Dim ptr As IntPtr = bmpData.Scan0

        ' Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap. 
        Dim numBytes As Integer = (Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * rect.Height)
        Dim rgbData(numBytes - 1) As Byte

        ' Copy the RGB values into the array.
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbData, 0, numBytes)

        ' Unlock the bits.
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData)

        ' Iterate the pixels.
        For i As Integer = 0 To (rgbData.Length - bytesPerPixel) Step bytesPerPixel

            Dim color As Color = color.FromArgb(red:=rgbData(i + 2),
                                                green:=rgbData(i + 1),
                                                blue:=rgbData(i))

            Dim position As Integer = (i \ bytesPerPixel)

            Dim location As Point =
                New Point(X:=(position Mod rect.Width),
                          Y:=(position - (position Mod rect.Width)) \ rect.Width)

            Yield New PixelInfo(color, position, location)

        Next i

    End If

End Function
```

---

### Problem

I've tested it for images with a pixelformat of `PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb` and `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`, it seems to work as expected.

The problem I have is that if I use an image with pixelformat of `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb`, all goes wrong, the `Color` I get does not correspond to the real color, and I also get more pixels than the image has.

---

### Question

Where I am failing in my calculations?, and how I could fix the functon to work with `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb` images?.

---

### Demostration

With the usage example below, I create a Bitmap of 2x2 size (4 pixels) with `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb` format, I fill the bitmap with the specified solid color, then I use my function to test the results.

```
Dim color As Color = color.FromArgb(255, 117, 228, 26)
Dim bmp As Bitmap =
    ImageUtil.CreateSolidcolorBitmap(New Size(2, 2), color, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)

Dim pxInfoCol As IEnumerable(Of PixelInfo) = bmp.GetPixelInfo()

For Each pxInfo As PixelInfo In pxInfoCol

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Position: {0}, Location: {1}, Color: {2}",
                      pxInfo.Position, pxInfo.Location, pxInfo.Color.ToString))

Next
```

This is the unexpected result of execution:

```
Position: 0, Location: {X=0,Y=0}, Color: Color [A=255, R=117, G=228, B=26]
Position: 1, Location: {X=1,Y=0}, Color: Color [A=255, R=117, G=228, B=26]
Position: 2, Location: {X=0,Y=1}, Color: Color [A=255, R=26, G=0, B=0]
Position: 3, Location: {X=1,Y=1}, Color: Color [A=255, R=26, G=117, B=228]
Position: 4, Location: {X=0,Y=2}, Color: Color [A=255, R=0, G=117, B=228]
```

There are 5 elements (for 5 pixels, when image has only 4 pixels) and the colors are not the same on element 2, 3 and 4.

I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you study the [BMP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) article over at wikipedia, especially the [Pixel storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_storage) section.

> The pixel format is defined by the DIB header or Extra bit masks. Each row in the Pixel array is **padded to a multiple of 4 bytes** in size

So the bytes in each row of a 2x2 24bppRgb bitmap will look like below. As you can see, each row have two "padding bytes" at the end.

[image: 2x2 24bppRgb]

```
B G R B G R P P B G R B G R P P
```

There will be no padding in a 4x2 24bppRgb bitmap as the bytes in each row is exactly 3 DWORDs.

[image: 4x2 24bppRgb]

```
B G R B G R B G R B G R B G R B G R B G R B G R
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the BitmapData.Stride Property into account when moving between rows in the bitmap. When in 32bpp the Stride will always equal Width*4, that's why your code is working, but in 24bpp that is not always the case.